# TriggerIO: Run web on different port

Tags: trigger.io, forge

How can I run `forge web` on a different port? I couldn't find anything on the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't yet! If you desperately need to change it, see the `run_web` method in `.template/generate_dynamic/web_tasks.py`.

**NB** if you alter the port there manually, changes will be lost if we re-download your templates!

We do have a better solution on the way, as the TODO implies...

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame really, 'cause the port 3000 is the default rails port. I guess I'll wait :)